# Referencing a Visual Studio solution in a different source control repository whose folder is different for different users

Tags: c#, visual-studio, reference

We have a C# test solution that contains a number of projects.  This solution is in its own repository in Mercurial.  We now need to access dev C# projects in a second repository.  We know we can "Add existing projects" in our solution, but the physical location of the second repository is sure to vary depending on the folder name chosen by those who cloned the solution.  We are concerned this will cause constant reference breakages.

We want to keep adding to our current QA solution but also reference the 5 other projects from the second repository.  Does anyone have a recommendation?

Comment: I recommend everyone have the same file path structure to prevent things like this happening.

Comment: Have you considered configuring an environment variable and altering the solution file to use it in the path(s)?

Comment: @MyCodeSucks Unfortunately, in many places where computers can be shared this isn't viable - or it's at least a little scary for the danger it puts across.

Comment: @GrantThomas: How is it "scary"? If everyone follows the same structure, then you never have to worry about situations like this. Or any other situation where you're communicating with someone about particular aspects of the project.

Comment: The dev team recommended an env variable.  Do I just create the hard-coded path and then edit the solution in notepad to use the env?  Ideally we would have standard paths, but there are dev offices in 3 countries and many more "personalities" too

Comment: The solution I am using is the one Grant Thomas suggested.

I added the hard-coded paths, then created an env variable and edited the solution file.

Thank you Mr.Thomas.

Answer (score -1):

I have used each of the following as solutions to this problem (you could use either, but not both).

1. Use a standard directory structure for your developers. For example:

   ```
   {basePath}/{user}/{repositoryName}
   ```

   This allows you to use relative paths to reference other repositories, as long as you know the `{repositoryName}` for the repository the project is contained in. Relative paths also allow you to use any `{basePath}`, so this quite a flexible system. **However**, there is always a concern that the version of your dependent projects may not be the expected version, potentially leading to strange outputs. For your issue reports, your developers will have to explicitly give the commit hash for *both* the main repository and the dependencies they are currently working with.
2. Use [subrepositories](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Subrepository). This automatically standardizes the directory structure of your dependent projects, and allows you to track commit hashes in your repository.